# How to show that $\lVert x(t)\rVert\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Assume that
$$
\frac{1}{t}\ln\lVert x(t)\rVert\to\beta > 0~\text{ as }t\to\infty, t\to -\infty
$$

I would like to know if then follows that 
$$
\lVert x(t)\rVert\to 0\text{ as }t\to\infty, t\to-\infty.
$$

Can you give me some help please?

Comment: What happens if $\|x(t)\|=e^t?$

Comment: Then $\lVert x(t)\rVert\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$ and $\lVert x(t)\rVert\to 0$ as $t\to -\infty$. So in this case the statement ist only true for $t\to -\infty$. But is it in common?